# Object teleporting to another posisiton - Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am developing a Tetris game. And I have a problem with an issue. I just implemented the Spawn of the pieces and automatic tumbling. However, when I went to test the collision on the wall and on the floor, the object is teleporting to the other side, as shown in the gif below.

I used `Rigidbody` and `Box Collider` with `OnTriggerEnter` and `OnTriggerExit`. To detect the collision and not cross the wall. Before implementing Spawn and the others, everything was working normally. Now, the object is teleporting when collid in the wall. What did I end up doing to make this happen? Here is code below before and after implementation.

[image]

Code before implementation:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Threading;
using UnityEngine;
using Debug = UnityEngine.Debug;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class Movimentacao : MonoBehaviour
{

    public bool Rotation;
    public bool Rotation360;
    bool collidedRight = true;
    bool collidedLeft = true;
    bool collidedBottom = true;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {

           transform.position += new Vector3(0.6775f, 0, 0);

            if (!collidedRight) {
                transform.position += new Vector3(-0.6775f, 0, 0);
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {

           transform.position += new Vector3(-0.6775f, 0, 0);

            if (!collidedLeft){
             transform.position += new Vector3(0.6775f, 0, 0);
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        {

           transform.position += new Vector3(0, -0.6775f, 0);

            if (!collidedBottom){
                transform.position += new Vector3(0, 0.6775f, 0);
            }

        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            if (Rotation)
            {
                if (!Rotation360)
                {
                    if (transform.rotation.z < 0)
                    {
                        if (collidedBottom)
                        {
                            transform.Rotate(0, 0, 90);
                        } 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (collidedBottom)
                        {
                            transform.Rotate(0, 0, -90);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (collidedBottom)
                    {
                        transform.Rotate(0, 0, -90);
                    }

                }
            }
        }



    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {

        if (Mathf.Sign(other.transform.position.x) == 1)
        {
            collidedRight = false;
        }
        if (Mathf.Sign(other.transform.position.y) == -1)
        {
            collidedBottom = false;
        }
        if (Mathf.Sign(other.transform.position.x) == -1)
        {
            collidedLeft = false;
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (!collidedRight)
        {
            collidedRight = true;
        }
        if (!collidedBottom)
        {
            collidedBottom = true;
        }
        if (!collidedLeft)
        {
            collidedLeft = true;
        }
    }

}
```

Code After Implementation:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Threading;
using UnityEngine;
using Debug = UnityEngine.Debug;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class Movimentacao : MonoBehaviour
{

    public bool Rotation;
    public bool Rotation360;
    public float queda;
    public float velocidade;
    public float timer;
    bool collidedRight = true;
    bool collidedLeft = true;
    bool collidedBottom = true;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        timer = velocidade;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.RightArrow) || Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftArrow) || Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.DownArrow))
            timer = velocidade;

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {

            timer += Time.deltaTime;

            if (timer > velocidade)
            {
                transform.position += new Vector3(0.6775f, 0, 0);
                timer = 0;
            }

            if (!collidedRight) {
                transform.position += new Vector3(-0.6775f, 0, 0);
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {

            timer += Time.deltaTime;

            if (timer > velocidade)
            {
                transform.position += new Vector3(-0.6775f, 0, 0);
                timer = 0;
            }

            if (!collidedLeft){
             transform.position += new Vector3(0.6775f, 0, 0);
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))// || Time.time - queda >= 1)
        {

            timer += Time.deltaTime;

            if (timer > velocidade)
            {
                transform.position += new Vector3(0, -0.6775f, 0);
                timer = 0;
            }

            if (!collidedBottom){
                transform.position += new Vector3(0, 0.6775f, 0);
            }

            //queda = Time.time;

        }

        if (Time.time - queda >= 1 && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        {
            transform.position += new Vector3(0, -0.6775f, 0);

            if (!collidedBottom)
            {
                transform.position += new Vector3(0, 0.6775f, 0);
            }
            queda = Time.time;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            if (Rotation)
            {
                if (!Rotation360)
                {
                    if (transform.rotation.z < 0)
                    {
                        if (collidedBottom)
                        {
                            transform.Rotate(0, 0, 90);
                        } 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (collidedBottom)
                        {
                            transform.Rotate(0, 0, -90);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (collidedBottom)
                    {
                        transform.Rotate(0, 0, -90);
                    }

                }
            }
        }



    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {

        if (Mathf.Sign(other.transform.position.x) == 1)
        {
            collidedRight = false;
        }
        if (Mathf.Sign(other.transform.position.y) == -1)
        {
            collidedBottom = false;
        }
        if (Mathf.Sign(other.transform.position.x) == -1)
        {
            collidedLeft = false;
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (!collidedRight)
        {
            collidedRight = true;
        }
        if (!collidedBottom)
        {
            collidedBottom = true;
        }
        if (!collidedLeft)
        {
            collidedLeft = true;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I'm just gonna start off with the solution and I'll explain why I did each step below:

1. Instead of checking for collisions using triggers, try disabling your colliders "IsTrigger" property on the cube and walls (In the inspector).
2. Next on your Rigidbody make sure "Use Gravity" and "Is Kinematic" are also off on the cube (In the inspector).
3. Finally, In the Rigidbody, under constraints freeze all rotation directions (In the inspector).

Explanation:

1. Colliders in Unity can be either well, a normal collider that interacts with other colliders or it can be a trigger. Triggers a normally used when you need to know when something happens without known exactly when it will happen. In the case of your project here, you could use colliders but as you saw it quickly complicated your code. Instead, it's a better choice to let the colliders, well collide, and do their thing. The Rigidbody component adds more functionality to your colliders allowing them to be stopped by other colliders in your scene. This is perfect for your walls as when we try to move passed them we get pushed back out by the Rigidbody. This removes the need for collision checks as the Rigidbody already handles it.
2. We turn off the "Use Gravity" property because as the name implies, it will cause the object to be affected by gravity which isn't something we want. We also turn off the "IsKinematic" because we want the object to respond to collisions with other colliders.
3. We freeze all the rotations in the Rigidbody since we don't want the physics engine to accidentally start rotating our block if we hit another object. We of course can still rotate the block via scripting by adjusting the transform as you've already been doing. We, however, don't want to freeze out position since we want the Rigidbody to stop us from going through other colliders.

Some Final Closing Notes:

- If adjust the blocks transform by too much "transform.position += someNewPosition;" you could accidentally end up on the other side of the wall. This happens since you moved the block pretty much completely passed the wall in one frame so the Rigidbody didn't have a chance to stop it. If this happens try either thickening up the walls or making the movement distance smaller.
- In your code, it looks like you are trying to move the block after some time passes. If this is what you are trying to do, you should probably consider moving the "timer += Time.deltaTime;" lines you have everwhere to the top of the Update method. Because "Time.deltaTime" only gives you the time between frames we should always add this to our ongoing timer every frame. This will allow the timer to count in real-time as each frame is called. It is already reset after every move which makes this an easy implementation.
- As for an answer as to why the weirdness you saw happens occurred. I can't for 100% give you a correct answer but it most likely has to do with your trigger implementation since you set a bool in the OnTriggerEnter method and wait for the Update method to fix the issue. Instead, if you choose to continue with the trigger idea or for future reference, you should get everything you need to get done (like fix the block's location) all inside the OnTriggerEnter method since you know there's an issue already when that method is called.

Hope this helps you out. Cheers.

Comment: Just disabling Triggeres, Rigidbody "Use Gravity" and "Is Kinematic" unchecked and freezing all the rotation, makes works again, and much better than before! Thank you very much for the help and the tips!